# Change variables in place in void function without arguments

Tags: c, function, pointers, variables, pass-by-reference

TLDR: I want to find a way to globally declare dynamically allocatable arrays which cannot be declared as just constant arrays due to the need to change the length of the arrays, depending on the number of equations, but most likely not the array data. These arrays need to be accessible by various functions contained in source files making up the program I'm writing.

I'm currently porting a program from Fortran to C and I want to declare some global variables for the entire program, which consists of several `.c` and `.h` files, so that the said variables could be used not only in the file where they are declared, but in other files as well. [Actually they are  "semi-variables" because what will change is the length of the arrays, which depends on the number of equations, the real aim of this question is to declare arrays that are to contain constant data, but that data can be contained in more array slots, so the arrays must be dynamically allocatable.] The problem is that these variables are dynamically allocatable arrays and these arrays have to be filled with some numbers.
This is how I declare the variables:

in the file `problemsize.h`:

```
extern double *GammaL;
```

in the file `problemsize.c`:

```
double *GammaL;
```

Then I try to create a function to fill the arrays by changing their values in place. The function would be called from some other `.c` files which `#include problemsize.h`. Now, I know that one could create a function like this:

```
void fill_array(double **GammaL, double **GammaR, double **GammaT, ...) {
    GammaL = malloc(arrayLength*sizeof(double));
    for (int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
        (*GammaL)[i] = 0.1;
    }
    GammaR = malloc(arrayLength*sizeof(double));
    for (int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
        (*GammaR)[i] = 0.2;
    }
    [...] // And so on
}
```

and then invoke this function from external `.c` files. But the thing is that I have many such arrays that would have to be passed as arguments to this function. I'm wondering if it is possible to have a function like the above to do the same job (change the arrays in place) without the need to invoke it with these arrays being the arguments?

Or is there some other solution that would solve this problem?

**Edit**: I had the impression that in C one could only change pointers in place by passing them as parameters to a function. Now, after some clarifications, it is clear that global variables can be changed by void functions without passing any parameters, which definitely makes sense.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199482/discussion-on-question-by-sequence-change-variables-in-place-in-void-function-wi).

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389393/how-can-i-improve-my-question-and-what-could-be-the-reasons-it-got-one-downvote)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your arrays are global, then there is no need to pass them as parameters. Any function can use them without any problem, and modify their values.

In short, this is what you can do in `problemsize.c`:

```
#define ARR_SIZE 4
double GammaL[ARR_SIZE];
double GammaR[ARR_SIZE];
double GammaT[ARR_SIZE];

void initialize_arrays(void) {
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        GammaL[i] = ...;
        GammaR[i] = ...;
        GammaT[i] = ...;
    }
}
```

Or, if your arrays don't have a fixed size:

```
size_t arr_size = 0;
double *GammaL;
double *GammaR;
double *GammaT;

void initialize_arrays(void) {
    size_t i;

    arr_size = /*... calculate somehow ... */;
    GammaL = malloc(arr_size * sizeof(double));
    GammaR = malloc(arr_size * sizeof(double));
    GammaT = malloc(arr_size * sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        GammaL[i] = ...;
        GammaR[i] = ...;
        GammaT[i] = ...;
    }
}
```